# Taking application to the cloud

Tags: cloud

Forgive me for asking a very noobish question.

I have often heard people just say the term "I want to take my application to the cloud".
Notwithstanding the fact that some people might just say it for the sake of using buzzwords.

I really want to understand the crux of it. What does it really mean to take an app to the cloud.

Answer (score 3):

There is taking an application to the 'web', where the application runs on a server, and delivers HTML, CSS, JavaScript and other goodies over the Internet, where it is presented to your users in the browser. This runs on a 'web server', a machine dedicated to doing the above.

When you go to the 'cloud', it's the logical next step, where the web server runs in an environment that can dynamically adjust to conditions such as demand.

Consider your app is visited by 1000 people per hour, and your web server can handle 2000 people per hour. You take out a commercial during the Superbowl, and on that one day, instead of 1000 people per hour, you have 100,000 people per hour. What do you do? With the 'web', you would have to have enough machines permanently assigned to your site to handle 100,000 users per hour. With the 'cloud' your web server isn't a physical machine, but a virtual one, so that in a circumstance such as the superbowl moment, you could spin up the extra virtual machines to meet the demand, and then spin them back down once it goes away.

Thus the cloud allows you to meet peak traffic without dedicated, wasted, expensive hardware.

Now as to how you would take an existing web app to the cloud -- there are 2 main ways.

1. Run it on virtualized infrastructure -- for example, instead of having your web app on a hosted server, run it on something like Google Compute Engine.
2. Rewrite it as a cloud app instead of a web app -- so, if your app is Java or PHP (for example) you can deploy it to Google App Engine, and get 'cloud' functionality automagically. It might require some rewriting though.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

[Google Docs](http://docs.google.com) is a good example of an application in the cloud. Microsoft answer to [Google Docs](http://docs.google.com) is [Office 365](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/online-software.aspx#fbid=z0PDRw_ufS3)

Comment: I agree that they are...what I am specifically asking about is what would you do to take an already existing web application to the cloud?

Comment: If its already a existing web application that its already in the "cloud". The "cloud", at least from what I know is any app and/or data that is stored offsite and is accessible by any electronic means.

Comment: Here is some good articles:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd430340.aspx
and 
http://www.readwriteweb.com/cloud/2011/03/the-road-to-the-cloud-how-do-y.php

Answer (score 0):

Typically to "take an application to the cloud" means to (at least partially) rewrite the app to turn it into a *web* app, which is just an application that serves web pages (which, of course, are rendered in the users' browsers).

Answer (score 0):

When you are going to deploy your application on the cloud, it could be on an IaaS or a PaaS, you should follow some patterns. I recommend you to read these [slides](http://www.slideshare.net/ndeloof/cloud-patterns-j1) about "Cloud Patterns" which will explain you how everything works on the cloud.

Also, I recommend you to read this [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_computing#Service_models), which explains you the difference between an IaaS and a PaaS.

Once of the benefits of the PaaS are related to the fact that:

- You don't need any infrastructure
- You don't need to install any software. The stack is pre-installed for you. You just need to deploy. Example about how to do it on a PaaS [here](http://developer-blog.cloudbees.com/2013/09/bind-your-java-application-to-your.html).
- You usually pay as you use. It means that you can scale up/down your app depending on the number of request that you have. Then, you will pay less or more depending on this.